# tyrning to create a chat sever using socket.io and I am getting an error I dont understand

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I cannot figure out why my chat server is not working, gettin this error,
i read that io.set(); does not exist anymore but what do I use in its place?

```
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 2016.3.3\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\owner\WebstormProjects\appChat\server.js
Server is running on port 3000...
Option log level is not valid. Please refer to the README.
C:\Users\owner\WebstormProjects\appChat\lib\chat_server.js:15
        guestNumber = assignGuestName(socket, guestNumber, nickNames, namesUsed);
                                      ^

ReferenceError: socket is not defined
    at Namespace.<anonymous> (C:\Users\owner\WebstormProjects\appChat\lib\chat_server.js:15:39)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Namespace.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Namespace.emit (C:\Users\owner\WebstormProjects\appChat\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:209:10)
    at C:\Users\owner\WebstormProjects\appChat\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:177:14
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

here is the code for my chat server using socket.io

```
 var socketio = require('socket.io');
var io;
var guestNumber = 1;
var nickNames = {};
var namesUsed = [];
var currentRoom = {};

// establishing connection logic
exports.listen = function(server){
    io = socketio.listen(server); //Start Socket.IO server, allowing it to piggyback on existing HTTP server
    io.set('log level', 1);
    io.sockets.on('connection', function(){ //Define how each user connection will be handled
        guestNumber = assignGuestName(socket, guestNumber, nickNames, namesUsed); //Assign a user a guest name when
                                                                                  //they connect
        JoinRoom(socket, 'Lobby');//Place user in lobby room when they connect

        handleMessageBroadcasting(socket, nickNames); //Handle user messages
        handleNameChangeAttempts(socket, nickNames, namesUsed);//name change attempts
        handleRoomJoining(socket); //and room creation/changes

        socket.on('rooms', function(){ //provide user with list of occupied rooms on request
            socket.emit('rooms', io.sockets.manager.rooms);
        });

        handleClientDisconnections(socket, nickNames, namesUsed); //Define clean up logic when user disconnects
    });
};

//assigning a guest name
function assignGuestName(socket, guestNumber, nickNames, namesUsed){
    var name = 'Guest' + guestNumber; //generate new guest name
    nickNames[socket.id] = name; //associate guest name with client connection ID
    socket.emit('nameResult', { //let user know there guest name
        success: true,
        name: name

    });
    namesUsed.push(name);
    return guestNumber + 1; //increment counter used to generate guest names
}

//Joining a room
function JoinRoom(socket, room){
    socket.join(room); //make user join room
    currentRoom[socket.id] = room; //note that user is now in this room
    socket.emit('joinResult', {room: room}); //let user know they are now in new room
    socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('message', { //let other users in room know that user has joined
        text: nickNames[socket.id] + 'has joined ' + room + '.'
    });

    var usersInRoom = io.sockets.clents(room); //Determine what other users are in same room as user
    if(usersInRoom.length > 1){ //if other users exist, summarize who they are
        var usersInRoomSummary = 'users Currently in ' + room + ':';
        for(var index in usersInRoom) {
            var userSocketId = usersInRoom[index].id;
            if (userSocketId != socket.id) {
                if (index > 0) {
                    usersInRoomSummary += ', ';
                }
                usersInRoomSummary += nickNames[userSocket.id];
            }
        }
            usersInRoom += '.';
            socket.emit('message', {text: usersInRoomSummary}); //Send summary of other users in the room to the user
    }
}

//logic to handle name-request attempts
function handleNameChangeAttempts(socket, nickNames, namesUsed){
    socket.on('nameAttempt', function(name){ //Add listener for nameAttempt events
       if(name.indexOf('Guest') == 0) { //Dont allow nicknames to begin withGuest
           socket.emit('nameResult', {
               success: false,
               message: 'Names cannot begin with "Guest".'
           });
       } else{
           if(namesUsed.indexOf(name) == -1) { //If name isn't already registered, register it.
               var previousName = nickNames[socket.id];
               var previousNameIndex = namesUsed.indexOf(previousName);
               namesUsed.push(name);
               nickNames[socket.id] = name;
               delete namesUsed[previousNameIndex]; //Remove previous name to make available to other clients
               socket.emit('nameResult', {
                   success: true,
                   name: name
               });
               socket.broadcast.to(currentRoom[socket.id]).emit('message', {
                   text: previousName + 'is now know as' + name + '.'
               });
           }else{
               socket.emit('nameResult', { // Send error to client if name is already registered
                   success: false,
                   message: 'That name is already in use'
               });
           }
       }
    });
}

//send chat messages
function handleMessageBroadcasting(socket){
    socket.on('message', function(message){
        socket.broadcast.to(message.room).emit('message', {
            text: nickNames(socket.id) + ': ' + message.text
        });
    });
}

// creating rooms
function handleRoomJoining(socket){
    socket.on('join', function(){
        var nameIndex = namesUsed.indexOf(nickNames[socket.id]);
        delete namesUsed[nameIndex];
        delete nickNames[socket.id];
    });
}

//handling user disconnections
function handleClientDisconnections (socket) {
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        var nameIndex = namesUsed.indexOf(nickNames[socket.id]);
        delete namesUsed[nameIndex];
        delete nickNames[socket.id];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function() {...});
```

to this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {...});
```

The key is that the newly connected `socket` is passed into the `.on('connection', ...)` handler and you have to declare and use that in order to communicate with the newly created connection.

Comment: thanks I believed it fixed that error because I am getting a differrent error, thanks for the info makes since... now on to the next stack trace lol

Comment: @SamuelM.King - If this answers the issue that you originally posted about, then you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points (which will eventually lead to more privileges here) for following the proper procedure here.  If you need to, you you can post your next issue as a new question (with proper detail about the next issue).